# Cypress - How I get element ID that I have only part of the name

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

If this is the ID - div id="events_list_5f15869ebc342"

I want to get this element but only to catch "events_list_"

how can i do it ? I can not grasp it, selenium has an include function here I can not find a way

Comment: I could suggest you `cy.get('*[id^="events_list_"]')`. It will target all elements starting with `events_list`, so in case you have several elements you will need some additional logic in order to filter them.